# I want to make two text in appbar

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

anyone know how to make two text in one top appbar and make them change color and pages when touch? I've been searching for like 1 week now and can't find the solution please help. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, have you tried solving the problem, do you have any code snippet ? or do you expect answers from here ?

Comment: @SARANSURYA Most people asking questions on a question and answer site generally expect answers, yes.  That is, after all, the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Make your own custom app bar.
Here I have included both the texts as desired in your case. You can customize more 
according to your design.



class CustomAppBar extends PreferredSize {
final String text1;
final String text2;
final double preferredSize;
CustomAppBar({
     this.text1,
     this.text2,
     this.preferredSize
  });

  @override

  final Size preferredSize;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Container(

      height: preferredSize.height,

      color: Colors.orange,

      alignment: Alignment.center,

      child: Row(

          children:[
                 Text(text1),

                 Text(text2)
              ]),
    );

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the TabBar widget as part of the AppBar widget.

Check the [Flutter cook book for tabs](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs)